# Fetching ssh git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github

### Command

```
git remote update
```

#### ERROR

```
Fetching origin 
Fetching ssh git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I use a username and password to access my git repo on GitHub. My git pulls work fine. How do I change my fetch commands to access the repo with a username and password too?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to leave this as a comment. GitHub have some troubleshooting documentation on this issue [help.github.com/en/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey](https://help.github.com/en/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey)

Answer (score -1):

Use HTTPS for your remote rather than SSH: you can update this with `git remote set-url <remote name> <new url>`.